# ADO Error: Automation error - The specified module could not be found

Tags: vb6, ado

My VB6 application which runs successfully on many machines is producing the above error on just 1 users machine.  Machine has Vista SP1 which means the MDAC installer will not work since MDAC 2.8 is already included.

Code that leads up to the error:

```
'Temp file to users temp directory:
FileName = C:\DOCUME~1\nmiller\LOCALS~1\Temp\TmpPrint.mdb 

Dim catADO As New ADOX.Catalog
catADO.Create "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FileName
```

Error happens on the .Create line.

Any help getting this user going would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a permission problem with the file? Perhaps on Vista, you need to grant permission on the file. We know that Vista has much tighter security, including file and folder access.

Comment: Not that I could see.  I logged in with CoPilot and was able to create/edit files in his temp directory with no problems.

Comment: The permission has to be granted to the app user, which is probably different from your own login.

Comment: How can I test this then?  The program is setup to run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The Jet / Desktop ODBC drivers are not included after MDAC 2.6. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271908 to get the Jet dirvers.